# Need help on making the recursive parser using pyparsing

Tags: python, recursion, parsing, pyparsing

I am trying the python pyparsing for parsing. I got stuck up while making the recursive parser.

Let me explain the problem

I want to make the Cartesian product of the elements. The syntax is

```
cross({elements },{element})
```

I put in more specific way

```
cross({a},{c1}) or cross({a,b},{c1}) or cross({a,b,c,d},{c1}) or
```

So the general form is first group will have n elements (a,b,c,d). The second group will have one element that so the final output will be Cartesian Product.

The syntax is to be made recursive because it can go to n level like

```
cross(cross({a,b},{c1}),{c2})
```

This means cross a,b with c1. Lets say outcome us y. We again cross y it with c2

This can be till n level cross(cross(cross(cross......

What i want is to have object to be initialized using setparseAction

So i will have 2 class

```
class object1(object):
     This will be used by a,b,c,d 

class object2(object):
       This will hold cross elements
```

I need help on this i am not able to make the recursive parser.

Answer (score 6):

You should look at definitions of other languages to see how this is usually handled.

For example, look at how multiplication is defined.

It isn't

```
{expression} * {expression}
```

Because the recursion is hard to deal with, and there's no implied left-to-right ordering.   What you see more often are things like

```
{term} + {factor}
{factor} * {unary-expression}
```

Which puts priorities and a left-to-right ordering around the operators.

Look at something like http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~pjj/bnf/c_syntax.bnf for examples of how things like this are commonly structured.

Comment: I dont need the expression to be used. I need this to do in python using the pyparsing only . The syntax is wrote is fixed and i think that can be done using the recursive parser.

Comment: @asb: Since other folks don't use recursive parsers for this kind of thing, I'm suggesting you might be more successful if you change the definition (not the syntax, but the way it's defined) to eliminate confusing recursion.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with @S.Lott you should reconsider your grammar.

Recursive definitions can be introduced using `Forward()`:

```
from pyparsing import (Literal, Word, OneOrMore, Forward, nums, alphas)

def BNF():
    """
    element      :: id
    elements     :: '{' element [ ',' element ]+ '}' 
                  | 'cross' '(' elements ',' '{' element '}' ')'
    """
    lcb, rcb, lb, rb, comma = [Literal(c).suppress() for c in '{}(),']
    element  = Word(alphas, alphas+nums+"_") # id
    elements = Forward()
    elements << ((lcb + element + OneOrMore(comma + element) + rcb) 
                 | (Literal('cross') + lb + elements + comma
                    + lcb + element + rcb + rb))
    return elements

print BNF().parseString("cross(cross({a,b},{c1}),{c2})")
```

Output:

```
['cross', 'cross', 'a', 'b', 'c1', 'c2']
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is any help, but here is how you would do what you want in lepl.  Since the grammar appears to be correct I assume that it would be easy to translate to pyparsing.

```
from lepl import *

def compile_parser():

    class Cross(Node): pass

    word = Token('[a-z0-9]+')
    par, en, bra, ket = [~Token('\\'+c) for c in '(){}']
    comma = ~Token(',')

    cross  = Delayed()
    vector = bra & word[1:,comma] & ket                 > list
    arg    = vector | cross
    cross += ~word('cross') & par & arg[2,comma] & en   > Cross

    parser = cross.string_parser()
    return lambda expr: parser(expr)[0]


if __name__ == '__main__':

    parser = compile_parser()
    print parser('cross({a},{c1})')
    print parser('cross({a,b},{c1})')
    print parser('cross({a,b,c,d},{c1})')
    print parser('cross(cross({a,b},{c1}),{c2})')
```

The output is:

```
Cross
 +- [u'a']
 `- [u'c1']

Cross
 +- [u'a', u'b']
 `- [u'c1']

Cross
 +- [u'a', u'b', u'c', u'd']
 `- [u'c1']

Cross
 +- Cross
 |   +- [u'a', u'b']
 |   `- [u'c1']
 `- [u'c2']
```