# Simple recursive descent in PyParsing

Tags: python, pyparsing, recursive-descent

I've tried taking [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634432/need-help-on-making-the-recursive-parser-using-pyparsing/634725#634725) and converting it to something for a project I'm working on for programming language processing, but I'm running into an issue with a simplified version:

```
op = oneOf( '+ - / *')
lparen, rparen = Literal('('), Literal(')')

expr = Forward()
expr << ( Word(nums) | ( expr + op + expr ) | ( lparen + expr + rparen) )
```

I've played around with a number of different modifications of this simple setup. Usually, trying something like:

```
print(expr.parseString('1+2'))
```

Will return `['1']`. While I get caught in deep recursion with something like:

```
print(expr.parseString('(1+2)'))
```

What am I missing with respect to simple recursion that I can't parse arbitrarily arithmetic expressions, such as `1+(2 * 3-(4*(5+6)-(7))...`?

Answer (score 27):

Wow, I guess pyparsing is really on the map!  Thanks Alex and John for stepping in on this question.  You are both on the mark with your responses.  But let me add a comment or two:

1. If we suppress the opening and closing parenthesis symbols, and group the parenthesized expression using Group, pyparsing will a structured result that is closer to an AST.

   ```
   from pyparsing import Literal,Word,ZeroOrMore,Forward,nums,oneOf,Group

   def Syntax():
       op = oneOf('+ -')
       lpar  = Literal( '(' ).suppress()
       rpar  = Literal( ')' ).suppress()
       num = Word(nums)
       expr = Forward()
       atom = num | Group(lpar + expr + rpar)
       expr << atom + ZeroOrMore(op + atom)
       return expr

   if __name__ == "__main__":
       expr = Syntax()
       def test(s):
           results = expr.parseString(s)
           print s,'->', results

       test( "(9 + 3)" )
       test( "(9 + 3) * (4 / 5)" )
   ```

   Giving:

   ```
   (9 + 3) -> [['9', '+', '3']]
   (9 + 3) * (4 / 5) -> [['9', '+', '3'], '*', ['4', '/', '5']]
   ```

   Otherwise, pyparsing is just tokenizing, and you have to walk the list of parsed tokens to find the nested expressions.
2. Since op is defined as just oneOf("+ - * /"), there is no precedence of operations.  There are examples on the pyparsing repo at https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/tree/master/examples of the manual way to define this (fourFn.py), or the more recent approach using the `infixNotation` helper (simpleArith.py).  Again, this has pyparsing adding more value than just tokenizing.

To the OP, please check out those examples, I think they will help move you forward on your project.

-- Paul

Answer (score 9):

Is this more or less what you want...?

```
from pyparsing import Literal,Word,ZeroOrMore,Forward,nums,oneOf

def Syntax():
    op = oneOf( '+ - / *')
    lpar  = Literal( '(' )
    rpar  = Literal( ')' )
    num = Word(nums)

    expr = Forward()
    atom = num | ( lpar + expr + rpar )
    expr << atom + ZeroOrMore( op + expr )
    return expr


if __name__ == "__main__":

    expr = Syntax()

    def test(s):
        results = expr.parseString( s )
        print s,'->', results

    test( "(9 + 3)" )
    test( "(9 + 3) * (4 / 5)" )
```

emitting

```
(9 + 3) -> ['(', '9', '+', '3', ')']
(9 + 3) * (4 / 5) -> ['(', '9', '+', '3', ')', '*', '(', '4', '/', '5', ')']
```

?  This "anchors" the recursion by separating an "atom" (number or parenthesized expression) from an "expression" (one or more "atoms" with operators in-between).

Answer (score 4):

A grammar like:

```
expr :: expr op expr
```

is hard to work with because the recursion just keeps diving into the left.

A normal arithmetic grammar would look something like:

```
expr :: mulxp | mulxp '+' expr
mulxp :: atom | atom '*' expr
atom :: Word(nums) | '(' + expr + ')'
```

Basically, you never get `S :: S`; any time a nonterminal appears on the left and right hand sides of a line in the grammar, there must be some literal in the middle for the parser to consume.

Comment: Could you please add some tips on how to convert `expr :: expr op expr` to some other form that Pyparsing can handle, for example in my case at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15438015/stack-overflow-when-pyparsing-ada-2005-scoped-identifiers-using-reference-manual

Answer (score 0):

Use `operatorPrecedence` to build expressions. It'll build the correct expressions, and take care of operator precedence while at it:

```
num = Word(nums)
plusop = oneOf( '+ -')
multop = oneOf('/ *')
expr = operatorPrecedence(num,
                          [(multop, 2, opAssoc.LEFT),(plusop, 2, opAssoc.LEFT)])
```

example:

```
>> print parsetime.expr.parseString("1+(2 * 3-(4*(5+6)-(7)))")
[['1', '+', [['2', '*', '3'], '-', [['4', '*', ['5', '+', '6']], '-', '7']]]]
```

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing