# Stack Overflow when Pyparsing Ada 2005 Scoped Identifiers using Reference Manual Grammar

Tags: python, stack-overflow, grammar, ada, pyparsing

I'm currently implementing an Ada 2005 parser using Pyparsing and the reference manual grammar rules. We need this in order to analyze and transform parts of our aging Ada-codebase to C/C++.

Most things work.

However, one little annoying problem remains:

The grammar rule `name` when parsing scoped identifiers (rule **selected_component**) such as the expression `"Global_Types.Integer2"` fails because it is part of a left-associative grammar rule cycle.

I believe this rule is incorrectly written: the sub-rule `direct_name` should be placed after the sub-rule `direct_name`. In fact it should be placed last in the list of alternatives. Otherwise `direct_name` and in turn `name` matches and `"Global_Types"` only and then expects the string to end after that. Not what I want.

Therefore I now move the rule `direct_name` to the end of `name`-alternatives...but then I instead get an Pyparsing infinite recursion and Python spits out maximum recursion depth exceeded.

I believe the problem is caused either by the fact that

- the associativity of the grammar rule **selected_component** is *right-to-left*. I've search the reference manual of Pyparsing but haven't found anything relevant. Should we treat dot (`.`) as an operator with right-to-left associativity or can we solve it throught extensions and restructurings of the grammar rules?
- or by the fact that there is no check in Pyparsing infinite recursions. I believe this wouldn't be too hard to implement. Use a map from currently active rules (functions) to source position/offset (`getTokensEndLoc()`) and always fail a rule if the current source input position/offset equals the position related to the rule just entered.

[Recursive expressions with pyparsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571441/recursive-expressions-with-pyparsing) may be related to my problem.

The problem also seems closely related to [Need help in parsing part of python grammar](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/message/view/home/51617848)
 which unfortunately doesn't have answers yet.

Here's the Ada 2005 grammar rule cycle that causes infinite recursion:

- [name](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-4-1.html#S0091) =>
- [selected_component](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-4-1-3.html#S0098) =>
- [prefix](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-4-1.html#S0093) =>
- [name](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-4-1.html#S0091)

Note that this problem is not an Ada-specific issue but is related to all grammars containing left-recursive rules.

Comment: Ada language lawyers hang out in comp.lang.ada, I'd give them a shot if I were you.

Comment: It would help if you copied the original grammar rules in the question.

Comment: @Apalala: I've added links to the grammar rules.

Comment: You might have more luck with a new question that strips your problem down to the bones? Looks like your problem is: how do you handle these three rules?  (1) A => B | C  (2) C => D "." E  (3) D => A | F  References to Ada and pyparsing could be putting off some grammar experts who don't know those specific technologies.

Comment: As @JohnFouhy says, you could post your PyParsing code for the problematic rules. 

Note that PyParsing doesn't seem to state it's parsing capabilities (LL(k), LALR(k), PEG?).

Comment: Cross-post [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.lang.ada/qZ1Cm586bcw/6nyG4BE_kycJ); follow-up [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15543818/230513).

Answer (score 1):

For reference, as noted in [*GNAT: The GNU Ada Compiler*](http://www2.adacore.com/gap-static/GNAT_Book/html/main.htm), [*§2.2 The Parser*](http://www2.adacore.com/gap-static/GNAT_Book/html/node6.htm#SECTION03220000000000000000), "The Ada grammar given [in] the [ARM](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-TOC.html) is ambiguous, and a table-driven parser would be forced to modify the grammar to make it acceptable to LL (1) or LALR (1) techniques."